# In function always false

Tags: arrays, crystal-reports

I have this formula in CR
I initialize in the group header

```
shared stringvar array HandAr := [""];
shared numbervar x :=1;
shared numbervar y :=0;
```

then in the detail section

```
shared stringvar array HandAr;
shared numbervar x;
shared numbervar y;

(if CStr({Material_Location.Material_Location},"######",0,"","") in HandAr[x] then x := x+0 else 
    y := y+{Material_Location.On_Hand_Qty};
    HandAr[x] := CStr({Material_Location.Material_Location},"######",0,"","");
    ReDim preserve HandAr[UBound (HandAr)+1];
    x := x+1;);
```

The formula never returns true

Comment: Actually it does not seem to return anything. Just add a line at the end with the var that should be returned.

Comment: I did not put the third formula that returns the results of the array.  It is there.  The problem is that the if statement never evaluates to false.  It always adds a to the array.  For example if there are four locations encountered in the records 101, 102, 101, 102  It returns a string of the array members 101,102,101,102 when it should return 101,102

Answer (score 0):

The correct detail formula would look like this:

```
shared stringvar array HandAr;
shared numbervar x;
shared numbervar y;

(if CStr({Material_Location.Material_Location},"######",0,"","") in HandAr then x := x+0 else 
  (
  y := y+{Material_Location.On_Hand_Qty};
  HandAr[x] := CStr({Material_Location.Material_Location},"######",0,"","");
  ReDim preserve HandAr[UBound (HandAr)+1];
  x := x+1;
  )
);
```

Where the following changes were made:

- brackets around commands in else block (I guessed from your last comment that's the way you wanted it to work)
- in if condition `in HandAr` instead of `in HandAr[x]`, to compare with all array elements